# Complex objects in closures

Tags: powershell, closures

I want to maintain state in a returned closure:

```
function HashMaker {

        $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
        $hasher = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider

        return {
            param($value)
            [System.BitConverter].ToString($hasher.ComputeHash($enc.GetBytes($value)))
        }.GetNewClosure()
}
```

There's obviously something wrong with this approach

Comment: What exactly wrong? What behavior you get? And how it different from what you expect?

Comment: Finding it really hard to guess at intent too. The code above returns a script block, but not a very useful one since neither $hasher nor $enc will exist once it's returned.

Comment: @ChrisDent They most certainly will (courtesy of `GetNewClosure()`)

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `ToString()` on the `[BitConverter]` *type* itself, call its *static* `ToString()` method:

```
return {
        param($value)
        [System.BitConverter]::ToString($hasher.ComputeHash($enc.GetBytes($value)))
    }.GetNewClosure()
```

Notice the `::` instead of `.`